# How to iterate through DOM nodelist/array

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how to iterate through an array of DOM elements.  I have an array of `div`s that contains `img` elements. I started with a nodelist but converted it to an array.  I'd like to be able to press specific buttons and have `div`s with certain classes disappear.  The event listener is functional because upon clicking a button the first element with the specified class disappears, just not the rest of the `div`s with the same class name.

The relevant HTML

```
<!-- list items for the project gallery -->
      <ul class="gallery-list">
        <li class="gallery-list-item all-button">All</li>
        <li class="gallery-list-item indoor-button">Indoor</li>
        <li class="gallery-list-item outdoor-button">Outdoor</li>
      </ul>
      <!-- flex container for gallery pictures -->
      <div class="gallery-flex-container">
        <!-- flex items / content images -->
        <div class="gallery-flex-item show-all indoor">
          <img src="images/indoor-1.jpg" alt="indoor garden picture">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-flex-item show-all outdoor">
          <img src="images/outdoor-1.jpg" alt="outdoor garden picture">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-flex-item show-all indoor">
          <img src="images/indoor-2.jpg" alt="indoor garden picture">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-flex-item show-all outdoor">
          <img src="images/outdoor-2.jpg" alt="outdoor garden picture">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-flex-item show-all indoor">
          <img src="images/indoor-3.jpg" alt="indoor garden picture">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-flex-item show-all outdoor">
          <img src="images/outdoor-3.jpg" alt="outdoor garden picture">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-flex-item show-all indoor">
          <img src="images/indoor-4.jpg" alt="indoor garden picture">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-flex-item show-all outdoor">
          <img src="images/outdoor-4.jpg" alt="outdoor garden picture">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-flex-item show-all indoor">
          <img src="images/indoor-5.jpg" alt="indoor garden picture">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-flex-item show-all outdoor">
          <img src="images/outdoor-5.jpg" alt="outdoor garden picture">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-flex-item show-all indoor">
          <img src="images/indoor-6.jpg" alt="indoor garden picture">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-flex-item show-all outdoor">
          <img src="images/outdoor-6.jpg" alt="outdoor garden picture">
        </div>
      </div>
```

The relevant CSS

```
.hide-indoor {
  display: none;
}

.hide-outdoor {
  display: none;
}
```

the relevant Javascript

```
// Script for gallery page picture toggle

let imgArray = [...document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-flex-item')];

console.log(imgArray);

var listItem = document.querySelector('.gallery-list');
var indoor = document.querySelector('.indoor');
var outdoor = document.querySelector('.outdoor');

listItem.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('all-button')) {
      indoor.classList.remove('hide-indoor');
      outdoor.classList.remove('hide-outdoor');

    } else if (e.target.classList.contains('indoor-button')) {

// Here is the section of code I tried incorporating the 'i' variable
// and it works the exact same as the other two 'if' statements.
// Only manipulating the first of elements with selected classes.

      if (imgArray[i].classList.contains('indoor')) {  
        indoor.classList.remove('hide-indoor');
      } else if (imgArray[i].classList.contains('outdoor')) {
        outdoor.classList.add('hide-outdoor');
      }

    } else if (e.target.classList.contains('outdoor-button')) {
      outdoor.classList.remove('hide-outdoor');
      indoor.classList.add('hide-indoor');
    }

  }
});
```

This is the first time I've tried iterating through DOM elements so I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simplified your code a little bit. This should get you started.

You do not need `hide-outdoor` and `hide-indoor` css classes that do the same. You can use shared `hide` class and apply it to different elements.

You also do not need `showAll` class. If the element is not hidden it will be visible.

```js
const getEl = (selector) => document.querySelector(selector);
const getAllEls = (selector) => [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];
const hideEl = (el) => el.classList.add('hide');
const showEl = (el) => el.classList.remove('hide');
const hideEls = (selector) => getAllEls(selector).forEach(hideEl);
const showEls = (selector) => getAllEls(selector).forEach(showEl);

const select = getEl('[data-all]');
const indoor = getEl('[data-indoor]');
const outdoor = getEl('[data-outdoor]');
const indoorEls = getAllEls('.indoor');
const outdoorEls = getAllEls('.outdoor');

select.addEventListener('click', () => {
  showEls('.indoor');
  showEls('.outdoor');
})

indoor.addEventListener('click', () => {
  showEls('.indoor');
  hideEls('.outdoor');
})

outdoor.addEventListener('click', () => {
  showEls('.outdoor');
  hideEls('.indoor');
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li data-all>All</li>
  <li data-indoor>Indoor</li>
  <li data-outdoor="">Outdoor</li>
</ul>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery-item  indoor">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="indoor garden picture">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item  outdoor">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="outdoor garden picture">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a masterpiece! Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: Please consider upvoting my answer and accepting this as a solution :)

Comment: Just as a point of interest,  why did you use data attributes rather than just using a classname or id?

Comment: I probably should have used ids, because you will only have one `all`, `indoor` and `outdoor` button. Didn't want to use classes, because they suggest that there might be multiple elements of this type.

Comment: I guess I still had this article in mind. https://medium.com/@colecodes/test-your-dom-with-data-attributes-44fccc43ed4b Some people suggest using `data-js` attributes if you want to target the element with javascript. This way you can keep classes and ids as css only properties, and use data props for javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the article as well.  I'm still new to this and need as much info as possible.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

> The event listener is functional because upon clicking a button the first element with the specified class disappears, just not the rest of the divs with the same class name.

Use `querySelectorAll` in place of `querySelector`.

`querySelectorAll` will return list of all the matching element nodes unlike `querySelector` which returns only the first matching element node.

For Reference: [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)